# Symfony 1.4 - PDO Connection Error: safe_mode/open_basedir prohibits opening

Tags: php, sqlite, symfony-1.4

I am using Mint 12,

I am trying to access to a symfony1 module in the browser and I get the next error message:
500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Connection_Exception
PDO Connection Error: safe_mode/open_basedir prohibits opening /home/user/projects/sf/form/symfony/data/database.db
I was following this practical
http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/13

There is not much information in relation in google. I found this link but it doesnt explains how to solve the problem.
http://devzone.zend.com/597/sqlite-lean-mean-db-machine/

I tried setting safe_mode=On/Off in my php.ini file, but nothing happends.
I really do not know how to solve this problem. Any help would be nice.
As I know there is not a problem with the access to the database, its sqlite and other modules work without a problem in Symfony 1.4

Thank you very Much

Comment: Did you set your webserver up to be able to access your home dir?

Comment: You mean if my webserver (Apache) is running?
Yes, it is running I can access to previous modules on symfony.

Comment: Well no i meant if Apache can access your home directory - typically Apache doesnt have permissions to read/write to that location unless you have set it up that way, but if you have access to the previous modules then that is not the case. Do you have `open_basedir` turned on and if so what is the value?

Comment: The values on my php.ini are

;open_basedir =
safe_mode = Off

Comment: you can have multiple php.ini files.. are you sure you edited/verified the one the server is actually using?

Comment: I can see with "locate php.ini" two files and in both I have the same settings. Really do not know how to fix it, thanks for the effort prodigitalson